# Dump byte array as hexadecimal values

Tags: javascript, firefox

In JavaScript on Firefox, a Uint8Array shows like this on the console, using `console.log`:

```
Uint8Array […]
0: 131
1: 165
2: 116
3: 111
4: 112
```

How can I make it show as hexadecimal values, like this:

```
Uint8Array […]
0: 0x83
1: 0xa5
2: 0x74
3: 0x6f
4: 0x70
```

I'm trying to debug some websocket communication and have to look up the bytes in the format specification which only lists the values in hex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't make the console do that (at least I know of no way to do that), but you could transform the array explicitly:

```
console.log([].map.call(yourArray, x => x.toString(16))
```

*edit* — thanks for the correction; the typed arrays return new typed arrays from their `.map()`.

You could also make it a regular array with `Array.from()`.

Comment: Using this, all values that have letters in their hex value are converted to 0. And the type remains a Uint8Array, not some string array. Trying to find the bug.

Comment: Doesn't work with `TypedArray` because their `map` [creates another typed array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/map).

Comment: @ygoe right that or just using the "normal" map version from plain arrays